# htaccess rewrite problem in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, .htaccess

I am fiddling around with .htaccess and mod_rewrite. I have a site that has two types of URLs which I rewrote:

- `/index.php?nav=$2`
- `/index.php?nav=41&intNewsId=$3` -- 41 is static, the news nav is always 41

I rewrote them to:

- `/pagename/id`
- `/news/pagename/id`

I already made a piece of code that works (below), I had some help from the community, but the weird thing is that http://www.mydomain.nl/projects/15 works fine in FF, Chrome and safari, but it gives "page cant be displayed" in IE. Does htaccess work differently in different browsers? (I highly doubt it)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Reroute rules that end on / 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\d+) /$1/$2/ [R] 
# RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(\d+) /$1/$2/$3/ [R] 

# Make the system understand pagename/96
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\d+)/ /index.php?nav=$2 

# Make the system understand news/pagename/99
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(\d+)/ /index.php?nav=41&intNewsId=$3
```

**I solved the problem**, but Im unsure why this does work, and the previous code doesnt. I fixed two things: I removed the starting / from /index.php... That didnt solve it, but it's less bytes :D

Then I rewrote the /-rerouting rule, this fixed it...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.nl/$1/ [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\d+)/ index.php?nav=$2 

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(\d+)/ index.php?nav=41&intNewsId=$3
```

Thanks all!

Comment: To answer your question: No, htaccess is server-side, and has absolutely no knowledge of what browser is being used.

Comment: @Hans If you can share a example of REAL URL then we may look into what IE does not like about such page. Quite possible it has to do with content/headers as URL Rewrite module does its job on server without looking at UserAgent ID String -- it is the same for all browsers.

Comment: Heya Lazyone,
Sorry, I cant send a real link, its localhost.. Can you point me in the right direction for those headers? Like what headers do you mean, MIME types of the file or...
@ Spudley: figures... thanks!

Comment: @Hans Well ... use FireBug for Forefox ("Net" panel) or similar tool for any other browser (Chrome, Opera, Safari (and maybe latest IE) -- they all have similar tools) and see the actual response headers. **BTW**, when replying to somebody who is not author of the answer/question, it is better to have his username prefixed with `@` as first thing in the comment -- otherwise person will not be notified about your response.

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks for the @ tip, Im new to the place :) I use Firebug in that matter btw, but even then it was abracadbra to me

Regarding the problem: I solved it, but I have no clue why... I'll post my solution as an edit.

Comment: @Hans Glad you solved it. Few Small advice: 1) try not to use `(.*)` in patterns like `^(.*)\/(.*)\/(\d+)/` -- this pattern will match your url (`/news/pagename/id/`) but it will also match `/news/blabla/pagename/id`/ or `/blabla/wuf/meow/oink/123/`. In your case it will be better to have `^news/([^/]+)/(\d+)/$` 2) No need to escape `/` character (you use `\/`) 3) instead of `(.*)` consider using `([^/]+)` for representing part of the URL path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, but Im unsure why this does work, and the previous code doesnt. I fixed two things: I removed the starting / from /index.php... That didnt solve it, but it's less bytes :D

Then I rewrote the /-rerouting rule, this fixed it...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.nl/$1/ [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\d+)/ index.php?nav=$2 

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(\d+)/ index.php?nav=41&intNewsId=$3
```