# .htaccess not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating one secure website by using .htaccess . Everything works fine in other browsers but the site not working in Internet Explorer. Its showing 404 error. Please help I dont know much about .htaccess problems.

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
#RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?localhost [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://openclipart.org/image/240px/svg_to_png/234001/no_glass_cameras.png [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
ServerSignature Off

# Disable Directory Browsing
Options All -Indexes

# Deny php direct accessing
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>

# DENY CODE

#<Files ~ "^.*">
#  Deny from all
#</Files>

#<Files ~ "^index\.php|css|js|.*\.png|.*\.jpg|.*\.gif|.*\.pdf">
#  Allow from all
#</Files>


#Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly; Secure"
```

Comment: Check similar ones : [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995747/htaccess-not-working-only-with-internet-explorer) , [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443961/htaccess-not-working-properly-in-ie) , [3](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76871/why-does-my-htaccess-work-for-all-browsers-but-internet-explorer) and [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452464/htaccess-rewrite-problem-in-ie). Also [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/htaccess-redirect-not-working-ie9/9507).